# Jenkins Plugin Installation

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have written a Jenkins Groovy Script for installing Jenkins plugin at startup. Groovy scripts are named after the Hook that is used to invoke my scripts. E.g. init.groovy is triggered inside the init-Hook. This Hook is triggered in post-initialization.

During initialization I have no access to the UpdateCenter and cannot install the plugins. What other Jenkins Hooks can I use? In my opinion I need a post-startup Hook.

This script works in script console but not inside post-initialization hook:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def pluginParameter="gitlab-plugin hipchat swarm"
def plugins = pluginParameter.split()
println(plugins)
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def pm = instance.getPluginManager()
def uc = instance.getUpdateCenter()
def installed = false

plugins.each {
  if (!pm.getPlugin(it)) {
    def plugin = uc.getPlugin(it)
    if (plugin) {
      println("Installing " + it)
      plugin.deploy()
      installed = true
    }
  }
}

instance.save()
if (installed)
instance.doSafeRestart()
```

> I need a hook where system is started and uc.getPlugin(it) does not return null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved this by asking the jenkins-irc channel. I needed to initialize the UpdateCenter's list of update sites. The result can be found here:
[blacklabelops/jenkins](https://github.com/blacklabelops/jenkins/blob/master/imagescripts/initplugins.sh#L22)

Comment: I think line #14 (uc.updateAllSites()) is redundant in your example.

Comment: Also, instance.doSafeRestart() interrupts installation of plugins.

Comment: Updatet the link to the latest jenkins 2 source code.

Comment: The script you linked is very helpful, thank you. Will save me a lot of time.

Comment: But will this not keep restarting Jenkins if the script is located in the init.groovy.d directory?