# How do I move Jenkins from one server to another?

Tags: jenkins

I need to move Jenkins version 2.32 from Server A  to Jenkins 2.72.1 Server B.
Both server have ubuntu 16.04.3
I could not install any plugin and take back up in Server A due to memory issues. Is there any way that I could achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move Jenkins from one PC to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy all the files in your `JENKINS_HOME` directory over to the new server.
2. Point `JENKINS_HOME` on the new server at the new directory.
3. Copy the Jenkins war file (or your servlet container setup if you have one) over to the new machine and start it up.

All Jenkins settings, jobs, plugins, config, etc. live in `JENKINS_HOME`. You just need a copy of it to start it elsewhere.

Comment: Will it not affect because I am using the latest version of my destination jenkins when compared to my source jenkins

Comment: I have yet to run into any issues with a Jenkins upgrade. As long as the version on the new machine is a newer version, when Jenkins starts, it will make any changes it needs to and chances are, it will go perfectly smooth.  This is even the process to upgrade from Jenkins 1.x to 2.x, and it worked without a hitch for me on several Jenkins instances.

Comment: @SaranyaUnni, were you able to successfully copy Jenkins from one machine to another?

Comment: The problem I have with this mode of moving Jenkins is that I cannot login at the other side, even after avoiding to move over secret.key, secret.key.not-so-secret and identity.key.enc. Is there a way moving Jenkins so that secrets and auth are not lost? or am I missing another file to avoid moving?

Answer (score 0):

Following [JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins), you still need to make a backup of `JENKINS_HOME`.

See also [How to Migrate a Jenkins Job to New Jenkins Server](https://staxmanade.com/2015/01/how-to-migrate-a-jenkins-job-to-new-jenkins-server/)

If you want to exclude the plugins for space issue, you can [list them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9815273/6309) in a text file, and [reload them with a groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31457623/6309).

Comment: I have followed [How to Migrate a Jenkins Job to New Jenkins Server](https://staxmanade.com/2015/01/how-to-migrate-a-jenkins-job-to-new-jenkins-server/) to copy jobs alone. But i need entire configuration of old jenkins

Comment: @SaranyaUnni Isn't that configuratio entirely in JENKINS_HOME?

Comment: @SaranyaUnni So my answer was valid, then?