# Migrating Jenkins Server from Windows to Linux machine

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, migration

I have a Jenkins server on Windows 7 and I want to migrate the same to a Oracle Linux server. What are the steps to be followed to make the migration smooth and error free?

P.S. I am using the Jenkins Community LTS 2.x edition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46335679/6309

Comment: i have not try with windows to Linux but when i migrate from CentOS to Ubuntu i just copy .jenkins folder